# How to open html page in tomcat docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat

I dont have any experience with docker or tomcat, so my question is most likely dumb. Googling didnt help in understanting what to do here so here i am.
I have a task with a few steps

1)Create Dockerfile based on tomcat:9.0-alpine

2)Add html page to dockerfile and add this project to tomcat

3)Launch container and open html page in browser

Can i open the page when launching image? Something like this:
FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine

RUN mkdir /usr/dock

COPY . /usr/dock/

WORKDIR /usr/dock/

CMD ["/usr/dock/index.html"]

I am on windows if it matters.
Would be really grateful for any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat is specifically a server for running packaged Java applications.  If you haven't already somehow placed the HTML file into a Java `.war` file then Tomcat probably isn't the server you need.

The easiest way to just serve a static page is with the [Nginx](https://nginx.org) Web server.  This has a matching [`nginx` Docker Hub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).  The Dockerfile can be as little as

```bash
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The base image already provides a `CMD` so you don't need to repeat it.

You don't specifically have to use Nginx here; any server that knows how to serve static files will work.  This includes Apache and the static-file-serving modules built into most Web frameworks.